# computer science or software engineering for game development?

Tags: education

I know this question is asked frequently, but I need your opinion on it to choose my path. I want to work in the game development. I know going to school isn't required to become a game developer. I'm trying to learn by myself, but without someone to help me or to guide me, it's useless. I hate learning by listenning videos...

Is software engineering worth it or it's a waste of time? I have watched the course curriculum and all the courses of computer science are in. Seems like software engineering is like computer science but with more knowledge. Those extra courses would be usefull or not. Both are offered with the computer games option thats really nice.

Also, for engineering I need one more year of school because I need physic and chimestry x.x and computer science is only 3 years. Does software engineering really worth 2 years of my life -.- ?

Comment: Opinion based question...

Comment: *Does software engineering really worth 2 years of my life*  Haven't you forgotten the 40 years of keyboard-slavery that inevitably follow a successful education in software engineering ?  Take my advice, transfer to an interpretive dance course NOW and enjoy the rest of your life in a leotard.

Comment: Sorry if my sentence offended you. What I mean is that engineering would cost me 2 years of experience in the domain. Is it really worth ? Since experience is an more important asset that studies.

Comment: Your question is going to solicit highly opinion based answers. There is no right or wrong answer this way and it won't help you much to make a decision. Technically speaking, CS is about the theory while Software Engineering is about the practical application of that theory. You can't be an engineer without knowing at least some of CS. Whether it is worth it or which path to take is an entirely different question. You can rephrase your question though, to make it much less subjective.

Comment: @Aless While schools might help. In my experience schools are almost completely useless when it comes to programming. In order to learn something actually, you have to DO something actually. Picking up a book/tutorial is a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in building/refining 3D game engines with realistic physics, then this more intensive software engineering program you've described *might* be worth the extra time and effort. Then again, computer science programs are generally sufficient (many institutions don't make a distinction between "computer science" and "software engineering"). If you're primarily interested in scripting and level design, computer science will more than suffice. So, it may depend on the *specifics* of what you want to do, but whichever program you choose, you should be able to land a relevant job eventually so long as you're diligently learning and practicing in the specific area of game development that interests you most.

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote, but please don't attempt to answer questions that break the rules of this site. OP's first sentence is "I know this question is asked frequently, but I need your opinion on it to choose my path." which literally breaks 2 rules.

Comment: Yeah, rookie error on my part. I appreciate the advice, @TomTsagk!